# how to check if key exists before adding in to dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

I am adding values in to the dictionary by using following linq code, right now what happens is duplicate key entry comes it is skipping both entries from dictionary, I need at least one to be present in dictionary. How to do it in the following LINQ code. I want it in LINQ only, code is as shown below:

```
dict = (from x in sites
        let pp1 = x.Split(',')
         where pp1.Length > 2
         let rnc = pp1[1].Replace("work=", "")
         let ems = pp1[2].Replace("Context=", "")
         let pp2 = GetName(ems, "CC", "U").Split('_')
         where pp2.Length > 1 && !ems.Contains("_L_")
         select new
         {
             name_ms = ems,
             Key = ems + "," + rnc,
             Value = Getidname(GetName(ems, "CC", "U"),
             GetCode(pp2[1])) + "," + ems.Split('_')[1]
         })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: what i want i let it add first one and skip the duplicate one in linq

Comment: That is exactly what this code in my example does `Select(g => g.First())`

Comment: `right now what happens is duplicate key entry comes it is skipping both entries from dictionary`. To be honest that is a surprise. I would expect it to throw an exception. Could you provide a [mcve] so we can see the shape of the source data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Frankly, I would wite a custom extension method to replace `ToDictionary`, but instead of using `Add`, using the indexer assignment:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionaryLast<TSource, TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach(var value in source)
        result[keySelector(value)] = valueSelector(value);
    return result;
}
```

which - in the case of duplicate keys - retains the last value, rather than failing. Then replace the last operation with:

```
.ToDictionaryLast(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: i am getting exception like type or namespace TSource could not be found like.. Is it TValue or  TSource???,if i change  TSource with  TValue  i am getting exception at calling side(.ToDictionaryLast) like cannot implicitly convert string to anonymoustype

Comment: @peter oh, sorry; fixing

Comment: Be sure that `x.Key` does not contain a `null` value or an `ArgumentNullException` will be thrown when trying to access the index as `result[keySelector(value)]`. Try checking for null within the `foreach` like `if (keySelector(value) != null)`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to group it by `Key` property and then `Select` `First` from grouped subitems. Then you will effectively skip records not being the first one in grouping by Key.

```
...).GroupBy(i => i.Key).Select(g => g.First()).ToDictionary(...
```

Comment: does that work ,since dictionery will not allow duplicates

Comment: what i want i let it add first one and skip the duplicate one in linq

Comment: I don't know what you mean. When you group by property `A` then there won't be duplicated values for that property

Comment: So try that modification and you will see the proof of what I wrote. It should do exactly what you want

Comment: No luck , i am adding 5000+ key values to dictionery, but i couldnot find   single value out of duplicates

Comment: `but i couldnot find single value out of duplicates` What does that mean @peter?

Comment: @peter: `GroupBy` effectively divides your list in smaller lists **per key value**. If you have two or more items with the same key, they will be added to the same list. Unique items will have their own separate list with no other items.  `Select(g => g.First())` then takes the first item from every list; which means that it can only ever take **one** item that has a particular key value.